# How to convert a logical vector of variable inputs into a function in matlab

Tags: matlab

Using a logical vector, I am asked to write a function that evaluates a piecewise function, and then write a script that plots the graph of that function by calling it. So the logical vector I've got is the following (from 0 to 1 the function's value is zero, so I avoid writing it.)

```
x=-2:6
y= (-x).*(x<0)+(x-1).*(1<x & x<=3)+(3).*(x>3);
plot(x,y)
```

The thing is that if I want to define this as a function, I did it like this:

```
x=-2:6;
function y=f(x)
y=(-x).*(x<0)+(x-1).*(1<x & x<=3)+(3).*(x>3);
end
```

MATLAB complains and it says that functions can not be written in this form.

Can someone help to write this code correctly please?

### New code

```
    function y=f(x)
    @(x)y=@(x)(-x).*(x<0)+(x-1).*(1<x & x<=3)+(3).*(x>3);
    end
```

then I've saved this as f.m so in my command window I wrote,

```
x=-2:6;
[y]=f(x);
plot(x,f(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can get this to work:

## Method #1 - Anonymous Functions

Did you try an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)?  All you have to do is use the `@` operator, followed by whatever variables that are part of the function... so **in the MATLAB Command Prompt**, type in:

```
>> f=@(x) (-x).*(x<0)+(x-1).*(1<x & x<=3)+(3).*(x>3);
```

Now that you're done, just call `f` normally with any input vector / matrix `x` **in the Command Prompt**:

```
>> x = -2:6;
>> out = f(x);
```

We get for `out`:

```
>> out

out =

     2     1     0     0     1     2     3     3     3
```

---

## Method #2 - Using Function Script Files

However, if you want to get your code to work, you can have to **remove the `x=-2:6` code at the beginning of your code**, then place this into a file:

```
%// NO x=-2:6 HERE!
function y=f(x)
y=(-x).*(x<0)+(x-1).*(1<x & x<=3)+(3).*(x>3);
end
```

If you want to write function files in MATLAB, the first line of the code **must be a function declaration**.  You're trying to make a normal MATLAB script file a MATLAB function file instead, which isn't allowed in MATLAB.

Though poorly named, you'd put this code into a function file `f.m`.... then you can call it normally:

```
>> x = -2:6;
>> out = f(x);
```

To finish things off, I refer you to this MathWorks help page that talks about how to properly write function files in MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but then if  I want to have a function defined as a logical vector I always have to put the @ first because this gives me a anonymous function that will mean a function enviroment for matlab and then it won't complaign right?

Comment: @user162343 - Correct.  It's still a function.  You can either create a file that stores the function, or make an anonymous function that escapes writing a file.  Totally up to you, but either one will work.  However, anonymous functions are designed for behaviour that can be encapsulated in one line, which is what you have here.  If you have more complex behaviour, you'll need to write an actual function file.

Comment: Ok, then in the second code I have posted I just have to add the @ in the definition of y and that's all right?

Comment: You need to add `@(x)` in front of the line and after `y=`, then call it like `y(x)`.  The `@(x)` is what makes the function an anonymous one.

Comment: @user162343 - Of course my friend.  I'll be waiting.

Comment: Just give me a while, because my computer locked out :) jajajaj

Comment: I've edited my post, but the thing is that MATLAB doesn't want me to run the code :(.

Comment: I am sorry for that :(, but I read your last comment and I didn't know how to interpret "in front of the line". I apologize for that.

Comment: Ok let me do it :) I hope you're not upset with me :)

Comment: @user162343 - No not at all.  Please forgive my outburst.  I've removed the comment.

Comment: Done :), just let me edit the post :) so you can see what I've done ;)

Comment: Make your `y` statement: `y=(-x).*(x<0)+(x-1).*(1<x & x<=3)+(3).*(x>3);`... this is NOT an anonymous function anymore... again, please read my Method #2 more carefully.

Comment: Right, but since we haven't use anynomous functions yet, I decided to use method 2

Comment: Yes :) It worked fine :) the only think that could be a mistake is that I have written other funtion , not the one I wanted to plot :) jajajaja

Comment: @user162343 - Ah heh. I see.